# python scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs giving different results for consecutive calls

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue

I am trying to compute the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of a sparse matrix in python. This is what I have:

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs
from scipy import sparse

w = sparse.rand(10, 10, 0.1)
spec_radius = max(abs(eigs(w)[0]))
```

where the values of `w` get scaled to be in the range of `[-1,1]`. However, running that command gives a different result every time:

```
>>> print max(abs(eigs(w)[0]))
4.51859016293e-05

>>> print max(abs(eigs(w)[0]))
4.02309443625e-06

>>> print max(abs(eigs(w)[0]))
3.7611221426e-05
```

What gives? I would have thought it would be the same every time. Am I misunderstanding how these commands work?

Comment: In the print command you use "w1"; above you defined "w" - is that just a typo? And if not, what is "w1"?

Comment: That's a typo, let me fix it

Comment: I tried it with exactly your code for different w. If "max(abs(eigs(w)[0]))" is greater than around 0.01 it works perfectly, and one always obtains the same output. But if "max(abs(eigs(w)[0]))" is far less than 0 - as in your example - one obtains indeed different outputs. The eigenvalues are computed using the [The Implicitly Restarted Arnoldi Method](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/UG/node45.html) which seems to be an iterative procedure. My guess is therefore, that one runs into issues when the eigenvalues are close to zero, it is just a numerical issue.

Comment: Ah, that must be the culprit then. In my actual code, the values of w are scaled to be in the range of [-1,1] before finding the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply the methods correctly and they will give you the same results if the absolute value of the largest eigenvalue is significantly larger than 0. The reason for the outcome you observe is based on the iterative nature of the algorithm that is used to determine the eigenvalues. From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html):

"This function is a wrapper to the ARPACK [R209] SNEUPD, DNEUPD, CNEUPD, ZNEUPD, functions which use the Implicitly Restarted Arnoldi Method to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors [R210]." In case you are interested in details of this algorithm, you can find an explanation e.g. [here.](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/UG/node45.html)

As in all numerical methods you can determine the desired value only with a certain precision. For eigenvalues that are significantly unequal to 0, you will always obtain the same output; for values that are close to 0 you might obtain different values as you observed in the above example.

You can try to vary the parameters "maxiter" and "tol" (check the above cited documentation for details) which you can pass to "eigs". Maxiter is the maximum number of Arnoldi update iterations allowed - by increasing the number you should get more accurate results. "Tol" is the relative accuracy for eigenvalues and stopping criterion of the algorithm.

Comment: I'm not entirely satisfied with this answer. Is there something random in ARPACK? E.g. a randomly generated starting vector for the iteration? Otherwise, I can't understand why running the exact same calculation twice gives different answers.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for responding to an old question here, but the other answer is not quite satisfactory.

The randomness is not part of the algorithm bundled with ARPACK, but rather the *initialization* of the algorithm.  From the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html) the initialization, v0, is random, unless specified by the user.  Sure enough, we see this (note the setup is slightly different--entries of w are scaled to be in [0,1]):

```
import numpy
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs
from scipy import sparse
w = sparse.rand(10, 10, 0.1)
w = w/w.max()
```

if we do not specify v0, we get some (slight) randomness:

```
>>> print max(abs(eigs(w)[0]))
0.00024188777676476916
>>> print max(abs(eigs(w)[0]))
0.00028073646868200566
>>> print max(abs(eigs(w)[0]))
0.00025250058038424729
>>> print max(abs(eigs(w)[0]))
0.00018183677959035711
```

but, if we specify, the initialization, we always get the same answer:

```
>>> print numpy.all([max(abs(eigs(w, v0 = numpy.ones(10))[0])) == 0.00026363015600771211 for k in range(1000)])
True
```